# Why does $\oint\frac{\delta Q}{T} = 0$ when evaluated over a Carnot cycle?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

In my thermodynamics schoolbook, it is asked to apply the Clausius inequality to a Carnot cycle. According to the book the answer is to evaluate $\oint\frac{\delta Q}{T}$ over the cycle which should yield
$$ \oint\frac{\delta Q}{T} = \frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{Q_C}{T_C}=0 $$

1. $Q_H$ is the heat transferred from the hot reservoir (positive)
2. $T_H$ is the temperature of the hot reservoir
3. $Q_C$ is the heat transferred to the cold reservoir (negative)
4. $T_C$ is the temperature of the cold reservoir

While it is easy enough to show this is true using $\delta Q =TdS$, my schoolbook doesn't introduce entropy until later. Therefore, my question is how to prove this equality **without using entropy** ?

Comment: Lay out a closed cycle involving the two adiabats and the two isotherms.  You won't be able to design one for which this equation is not satisfied.  Try it and see.

Comment: Hey there, is there a general way to prove that without using $pV=RT$ ? I know that from $pV=RT$ one can show that for a Carnot cycle $\frac{Q_C}{Q_H}=\frac{T_C}{T_H}$, which then shows that $\frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{Q_C}{T_C}=0$. Otherwise, I don't know how to show $\frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{Q_C}{T_C}=0$ always holds true for those types of cycles.

Comment: What's wrong with using pV=RT?

Comment: I thought this was valid for *any* fluid, not just ideal gases.

Comment: It, of course, should be true for any fluid.  But solving the equations for, say, a van der Waals gas might be a little challenging.  Maybe you are up to such a challenge.

Comment: Sure, there are more general equations out there that could help generalize it a little bit. In the meantime I found sources stating that $Q_H$ and $Q_C$ are both zero because of the constraint of reversibility  of the Carnot cycle, which would trivially prove that $\frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{Q_C}{T_C}=0$ for any fluid. I think I better understand how everything fits together now, thank you for your time and effort !

Answer (score 1):

I only know a long ride for this, sorry :/

You have to imagine two processes *iabf* and *if* that have the same work $\Delta W_{iabf}=\Delta W_{if}$:
[image]
(Dashed lines are adiabatic curves and solide lines are isothermes)

The internal energy variation is the same for both processes and $\Delta Q_{ab}=\Delta Q_{if}$.

Now imagine a system S' that provides energy $\Delta Q$ to the cycle C(system S).
[image]
The only way to enter energy is through an isotherm, with temperature $T_0=T_H$. This works as the hot reservoir. The *ab* isotherm has $T<T_0$, which is your $T_C$.
The system S' transfers heat($\Delta Q' $) to S:
$$\Delta Q' = T_H \frac{\Delta Q}{T_C}$$

The *cd* path has the opposite direction. **Try drawing one Carnot Cycle above the other and you will see they cancel each other.**

Now imagine infine mini carnot cycles inside C, the sum of all cycles cancel each other:

$$ \Sigma \Delta Q' = \oint_C T_C \frac{dQ}{T} = 0 $$
*T varies in each mini cycle.

Moving $T_C$
$$\oint_C \frac{dQ}{T} = 0$$

I believe your book assume reversible processes from the begining. Otherwise, according to the second law:

$$\oint_C \frac{dQ}{T} \leq 0$$

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering my question. I'm a little bit confused about $\Delta Q'$ though, is it the heat exchanged in the c-d isothermal ?

If so, why does $\Delta Q'$ equal $\frac{T_H}{T_C}\Delta Q$ ? Does that come from $pV=RT$ ? Or can we show that  $\Delta Q' = \frac{T_H}{T_C}\Delta Q$ without using $pV=RT$ ?

Comment: cd is an isotherm. The relation in $\Delta Q'$ comes from a reversible cycle between two reservatories, one with temperature $T_H$ and other with $T_C$. Or you can think about the thermal effitiency: $\eta=1- \frac{T_C}{T_H}=1-\frac{Q_C}{Q_H}$. Thus, $Q_H=T_C \frac{Q_C}{T_H}$ which is written with a diffferent notation: $\Delta Q'=\frac{T_H}{T_C} \Delta Q$ .

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that $$\oint_\gamma\frac{\delta Q}{T} = \frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{Q_C}{T_C}=0\tag 1$$

without referencing entropy.

It would be really easy to just say

$$\oint_\gamma\frac{\delta Q}{T}=\oint_\gamma dS=0$$ because a loop integral of a state variable is path invariant, but we don't want to do that.

It seems that we can prove the equality $(1)$ if we just prove that:

$$\frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{Q_C}{T_C}=0.$$

Now if $Q_C$ is negative lets write it as

$$\frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{-Q_C}{T_C}=0$$

than we have the following expression, which we want to prove:

$$\frac{Q_H}{T_H}=\frac{Q_C}{T_C}\tag 2.$$

Now we can prove the Carnot's theorem and from that proof we conclude that:

$$\frac{Q_C}{Q_H}=f(T_C,T_H)$$

and one funtion $f$ which Lord Kelvin choose as appropriate here is:

$$\frac{Q_C}{Q_H}=\frac{T_C}{T_H}$$

and now we just do an algebraic manipulation and end up with:

$$\frac{Q_C}{T_C}=\frac{Q_H}{T_H}$$

and that is exactly the equation $(2)$ which we wanted to prove.

Now we input it into $(1)$ and get:

$$\oint_\gamma\frac{\delta Q}{T} = \frac{Q_H}{T_H}+\frac{-Q_C}{T_C}=\frac{Q_C}{T_C}+\frac{-Q_C}{T_C}=0.  $$
Q.E.D.